# Flask server cannot read file uploaded by POST request

Tags: javascript, python, reactjs, flask, fetch-api

I have my React client post a file with the fetch api to the '/dataset' endpoint.

```
import 'whatwg-fetch';

uploadData(csv) {
    this.dataset = csv;

    fetch('/dataset', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: this._fileToFormData(csv)
    }).then(
        (response) => {
            console.log(response);
        }
    ).catch( () => {} );
};

_fileToFormData(file) {
        var formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('file', file);
        return formData
    };
```

My Flask server is supposed to pick it up.

```
@app.route('/dataset', methods=['POST'])
def dataset():
    print request.get_data()
    csv_data = request.form['file']
    print csv_data
    return '{ "fake_json":100}', 200
```

However, the `csv_data` object is simply a unicode string, `'[object File]'`

The code

```
print "form:", request.form
print "files:", request.files
```

returns

```
ImmutableMultiDict([('file', u'[object File]')])
ImmutableMultiDict([])
```

How do I get the actual contents of the CSV file?

=== EDIT: Solved ===

the variable csv was actually a single file array, so I needed to extract the file out.

Comment: have you tried file.read() rather than returning the file object from the form?  i think it would look like, csv_data.read()  ?

Comment: Yeah, I get an error saying that the unicode object doesn't have the method .read :/

Comment: Have you tried explicitly specifying the `Content-Type` to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` or `multipart/form-data` ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Uploaded files are available in `request.files`, not `request.form`.  The values are file-like objects, so to get the data you need to read the file.

```
data = request.files['file'].read()
```

See the Flask [docs](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/patterns/fileuploads/) for some examples on working with uploads.

---

You also need to upload the file correctly.  GitHub's [fetch polyfill](https://github.com/github/fetch#file-upload) has an example using `FormData` to format the body properly.  You must pass a single file or input to each call to `append`.

```javascript
var input = document.querySelector('input[type="file"]')
var data = new FormData()
data.append('file', input.files[0])

fetch('/dataset', {
  method: 'POST',
  body: data
})
```